# Почему ошибка "Неправильный синтаксис около конструкции "M""

Tags: sql

Пытаюсь создать таблицу:

```
    Create table person
    ('person_id' Smallint,
    'fname' Varchar(20),
    'lname' Varchar(20),
    'gender' ENUM ('M','F'),
    'birth_date' Date,
    'address' Varchar(30),
    'city' Varchar(20),
    'state' Varchar(20),
    'country' Varchar(20),
    'postal_code' Varchar(20),
    Constraint 'pk_person' Primary key ('person_id')
);
```

По выполнении даёт ошибку: Неправильный синтаксис около конструкции "M".

Не пойму: что не так?

И строку с Constraint тоже подчёркивает. Предполагаю проблемы будут и там.

Листинг взят с MySQL. То есть предполагаю с синтаксисом какие-то траблы...

Тестю на MS SQL 2017 (ошибка пишется в MS SQL Mgmt St). А листинг MySQL. Читаю Бьюли. У него на MySQL, но он божится что синтаксис одинаков...

Поменял листинг на следующий:

```
Create table person
([person_id] smallint,
[fname] Varchar(20),
[lname] Varchar(20),
[gender] char(1),
[birth_date] Date,
[address] Varchar(30),
[city] Varchar(20),
[state] Varchar(20),
[country] Varchar(20),
[postal_code] Varchar(20),
Constraint [pk_person] Primary key ([person_id])
);
```

и таблица создалась, так как поменял enum на char. Но это не хорошее решение...

Вопрос с синтаксисом ENUM ('M','F') оставляю открытым... (почему ругается на синтаксис перед М)

По рекомендации (stackoverflow.com/questions/1434298/…) скрипт переделан:

```
Create table person
([person_id] smallint,
[fname] Varchar(20),
[lname] Varchar(20),
[gender] char(1) NOT NULL CHECK ([gender] IN('M', 'F')),
[birth_date] Date,
[address] Varchar(30),
[city] Varchar(20),
[state] Varchar(20),
[country] Varchar(20),
[postal_code] Varchar(20),
Constraint [pk_person] Primary key ([person_id])
);
```

Таблица создалась и вроде бы по sp_help ограничение установилось.

Comment: Подчеркивает кто, какая база данных ? типы данных и некоторый синтаксис различается у разных СУБД. И лично я не знаю ни одной СУБД в которой имена колонок в таблицах заключались в одиночные прямые кавычки (у MySQL обратные используются)

Comment: MSSQL2017. Подчёркивает MSSQLMS

Comment: Поменял апостроф у имён столбцов на кавычки и теперь всё равно ругается на М у ENUM

Comment: ну вот и я удивлён кавычкам -((

Comment: Поменял все кавычки на апостроф (э на русской раскладке). Теперь ваще ругпется на 'person_id' Smallint, -> Неправильный синтаксис около конструкции "person_id".

Comment: MS SQL 2017. А листинг MySQL. Читаю Бьюли. У него на MySQL, но он божится что синтаксис одинаков...

Comment: Ой. Сорян. Я новенький.. Ща добавлю в тело вопроса

Comment: Типа данных enum в ms sql нет. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434298/sql-server-equivalent-to-mysql-enum-data-type

Comment: Подскажите плиз: как же теперь закрыть вопрос то?

Comment: под текстом вопроса "удалить", где то рядом с "редактировать"